# How to port assembly code for processor speed to Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, assembly, time, porting

I have the following code that needs to be ported to Visual Studio 2008. It computes how many cycles the processor completes in a microsecond in order to compute the processor speed:

```
typedef unsigned long long TProcessorClockTicks;

inline TProcessorClockTicks readProcessorTimeStamp()
{
#   if defined(_ARCH_linux_24_i86) ||               \
    defined(_ARCH_linux_26_i86) ||              \
    defined(_ARCH_cygwin) ||                    \
    defined(_ARCH_freebsd_61_i86)
        TProcessorClockTicks x;
        __asm__ volatile (".byte 0x0f, 0x31" : "=A" (x));
        return x / 1000;
#   elif defined(_ARCH_sol2)
        return (TProcessorClockTicks) ::gethrtime();
#   else
#       error  Must define _ARCH_??? preprocessor macro to build    \
        this code!
#   endif
}

typedef unsigned long long TProcMHz;

inline
TProcMHz
measureProcessorSpeedMHz()
{
  // Get the number of the processor clock cycles in a microsecond which should
  // be the processor clock speed in MHz.
  ::usleep(1);  // Put a sleep before to ensure accurate measurement.

  TProcessorClockTicks before = readProcessorTimeStamp();

  ::usleep(1); 

  TProcessorClockTicks after = readProcessorTimeStamp();

  return (TProcMHz) (after - before); 
}
```

What is the replacement for the readProcessorTimeStamp() body?

```
    TProcessorClockTicks x;
    __asm__ volatile (".byte 0x0f, 0x31" : "=A" (x));
    return x / 1000;
```

Comment: I don't think this is going to work.  Also, ::gethrtime returns nanoseconds, not clock ticks, and so that case of code would return the same thing regardless of clock speed.

Comment: You do realize this method is not accurate? sleep/usleep will not sleep for exactly the amount of time specified, only an approximation. If you want accurate info on windows, consider using the WMI Win32_Processor class (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: At the moment I'm not too concerned about how accurate it is and just want it to be in the ball park and ported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code assumes that `::usleep(1)` sleeps for exactly one microsecond. I don't know if that's a good assumption on a Linux box. It's certainly not a good assumption in Windows. At least, not in user mode.

Under Windows, there aren't any standard microsecond-level timers. The best you can do with the standard API calls is one millisecond, and even that's variable. In order to get a reasonable estimate of the clock speed, you'll need to get the elapsed time as well as the number of ticks elapsed.

Or you can query the registry for it. See http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/Processor_Speed.aspx for some options.